Unable to Access Location - Error Mounting /dev/sda1 (wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock, etc.)
I'm encountering an issue when trying to mount a partition in Ubuntu. When I attempt to access the partition, I receive the following error message:
Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/moe404/[partition_id]: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
Screenshot:
Additional Information:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Disk Information: /dev/sda1 is a partition on my internal/external hard drive.
Actions Taken: I haven't made any recent changes to the disk or system configuration. This error occurred unexpectedly when I tried to access the partition.
Attempted Solutions: I tried rebooting the system, checking the disk with fsck, and searching for similar issues, but I haven't found a solution that works.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Check logs (journalctl -r) for more detailed error message. Does mounting it manually from command line using mount works (I assume the error happens when mounting from the file manager)? What filesystem type is on the device?

You may also want to look at the output of smartctl -x /dev/sda as well & check for errors as well running the self-tests. Perhaps you or someone else inadvertently overwrote it in some way.

Try fsck /dev/sda1

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup
